# SSH using python to login to server, and reach command prompt on remote server

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am little short on time, and excuse if I have missed the obvious while searching for an answer.

I want to write a script in Python which will allow me to ssh into a machine. For some reasons we cannot use passwordless logins via SSH Keygens which is the easiest way to do. Reasons are not important, but real.

I tried  paramiko and pexpect.  Both allow me to run commands on a server. Works like a charm. But nowhere in the APIs I am able to create shell

What I need a script to enter into the shell prompt of remote server. I will know the username, password, servername, port number etc. The script should run and exit with the user being in the command prompt on the remote server. That's it.

Comment: `pexpect.spawn("ssh username@host.com").interact()`

Comment: That will prompt the password.

Comment: So you want to implement a program like `ssh` (interactive SSH client) using Paramiko? -- I probably do understand your question. -- What is your problem, the password authentication? Or *"creating shell"*? (whatever that means)

Comment: @ramdaz What I was trying to convey to you, is that there is a solution to your question about opening a shell using pexpect. Just use ANY example for establishing an ssh-session (like [this one](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html)) and call `.interact()` on it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, yes, I just need to login to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind. @Hampus Larson is correct. This code works. Manyy Thanks

```
import pexpect, time
child = pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/ssh user@xyz.com')
child.expect("password:", timeout=120) 
child.sendline('pass123#')
child.interact()
```